# Cómo dividir los requisitos de un proyecto con pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

En el desarrollo de mi proyecto de Django tengo una configuración diferenciada para producción y para desarrollo. Ambas tienen una configuración común y los ajustes de cada entorno van en su respectivo archivo.

Pero esto significa que tienen requisitos diferentes. Por ejemplo, en desarrollo uso el paquete `django-debug-toolbar` y en producción, no. Por otro lado, en producción uso el paquete `gunicorn` y en desarrollo no.

Y al igual que la configuración del proyecto, hay paquetes que son comunes a ambos entornos.

Pero todos los paquetes, actualmente, están en el mismo archivo de requisitos que se creó cuando hice:

```
$ pip freeze > requisitos.txt
```

Entonces...

#### Cómo puedo hacer dividir los requisitos de mi proyecto, en requisitos comunes, para desarrollo y para producción.

<sup><sup>...porque espero que sea posible</sup></sup>

Comment: Usas `virtualenv`?

Comment: Si. O bueno, uso pyenv.

Comment: Manejar dos entornos virtuales para desa y testing con dos archivos, por ej.  desa.txt y prod.txt con los requerimientos propios de cada entorno y usar `pip install -r desa.txt`, te parece una solución muy elemental? sino me extiendo un poco más en una respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, no. Ponla como respuesta, por favor. Mi objetivo es cumplir con estos requisitos: https://12factor.net/es/dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré esta respuesta en SOen pero pero perdí la referencia. Desafortunadamente, esta funcionalidad no está correctamente documentada por lo que podría pasar desapercibida.

Tal como lo documenta la [excelente respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91539/638) de [**Patricio Moracho**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764), usando `pip` podemos crear archivos de requisitos, pero en esta alternativa, evitamos que en los archivos se repitan los paquetes haciendo tres archivos de requisitos diferentes:

- `base.txt` - que contiene los paquetes comunes a los entornos usados
- `local.txt` - que en este ejemplo contienen los paquetes que *solo* se usan en desarrollo local
- `prod.txt` - contiene los paquetes que *solo* se usan en producción.

### Archivo *base.txt*

Este es un archivo de requisitos normal

```
Django==1.11.3
django-admin-tools==0.8.1
django-authtools==1.6.0
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-environ==0.4.3
django-taggit==0.22.1
django-taggit-templatetags2==1.6.1
Markdown==2.6.8
psycopg2==2.7.3
Pygments==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.2
rollbar==0.13.12
Unipath==1.1
```

### Archivo *local.txt*

El archivo de requisitos puede tener varios comando, que se *medio* explican en la [documentación de `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format), incluyendo **referencias a otros archivos de requisitos** y es aquí donde ocurre la magia:

```
-r base.txt
django-debug-toolbar
```

Este archivo indica que se instalen **primero** los paquetes indicados en `base.txt` y luego los que aparecen a continuación (en este caso, solo uno).

#### Archivo *prod.txt*

Aquí se enlistan los paquetes usados en producción.

```
-r base.txt
gunicorn
django-redis-cache
```

#### Uso

Entonces, para instalar los paquetes en el entorno de desarrollo, hay que hacer esto:

```
pip install -r local.txt
```

Y en el servidor de producción:

```
pip install -r prod.txt
```

> #### Nota
>
> Las referencias de versiones son opcionales, pero se generaron inicialmente con el comando `pip freeze base.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente es una propuesta bastante básica para manejar entornos aislados totalmente independientes, simple por que solo requiere de:

1. Python (la versión que corresponda)
2. pip, a menos que tengas Python 2.7.9+ o Python 3.4+, dónde ya está inluído
3. [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Además de simple es totalmente compatible tanto en Linux, como en Windows  o MAC. Se basa en [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), esta herramienta, básicamente "crea" entornos Python locales aislados en carpetas especificas y la idea es que uno "activa" estos entornos según sus propias necesidades, podríamos mantener un entorno para desarrollo y otro para testing, o bien crear uno nuevo de desarrollo para probar nuevas versiones de determinado paquete o incluso una nueva versión de Python, todo esto en el marco de una carpeta local si necesidad de privilegios de administración ni de modificar el sistema.

Veamos tu situación. Ya tenemos la versión de python que vamos a usar en el proyecto instalada y funcionando en el sistema, tenemos `pip` instalado y actualizado. Bien, lo primero va a ser instalar [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), simple: `pip install virtualenv`, y ya estamos listos para comenzar.

Lo habitual es crear estos entornos "virtualenv" como subcarpetas de nuestro proyecto, pero puede ser en cualquier lugar del sistema. Supongamos que nuestro proyecto está en `~/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto`, vamos a crear un entorno para desarrollo en Python 3x en esa carpeta y lo llamaremos `venv-desa` (el nombre es lo de menos), haremos

```
# cd ~/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/
# virtualenv -p python3 venv-desa
```

Con esto hemos creado una carpeta `~/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/venv-desa` y en ella hemos instalado: Python (3x) y unos paquetes básicos `setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel`, nada más y nada menos. Ahora simplemente debemos "activarlo", este proceso simplemente modifica el `path` y alguna que otra variable de entorno para apuntar a nuestra carpeta `venv-desa`. La activación en Linux se realiza, parado en la carpeta root del proyecto:

```
source venv-desa/bin/activate
# o de la forma más compacta
. venv-desa/bin/activate
```

En Windows cambia un poco nada más

```
venv-desa\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Independientemente del sistema los efectos son los mismos:

```
(venv-desa) # which python
/home/usuario/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/venv-desa/bin/python
(venv-desa) # which pip
/home/usuario/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/venv-desa/bin/pip
(venv-desa) # echo $PATH
/home/usuario/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/venv-desa/bin:/home/usuario/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Por un lado, nos modificó el "prompt" indicando el nombre del entorno virtual y por el otro modificó el path, para que cuando corramos cualquiera de las herramientas de python y python en sí, lo hagamos desde esta nueva carpeta. Ahora solo nos queda instalar las librerías o paquetes que vamos a usar para nuestro entorno de desarrollo, simplemente con el comando `pip install [paquete]`, todo lo que instalemos terminará en esta nueva carpeta. Por último si hacemos `pip freeze > desa-requirements.txt` tendremos nuestra lista de requerimientos para nuestro entorno de desarrollo, el cual nos servirá si debemos regenerar el entorno. Si queremos desactivar nuestro entorno, simplemente hacemos `# deactivate`.

Ahora, vemos que armar un entorno de testing `venv-test` solo variará en los paquetes que instalemos y por último: `pip freeze > test-requirements.txt`. Al final tendremos nuestros dos entornos `venv-desa` y `venv-test` con sus paquetes propios totalmente aislados y que podremos usar alternativamente o incluso al mismo tiempo en distintas terminales. Si necesitamos "regenerar" cualquiera de los dos entornos, en otro equipo o incluso SO, los pasos son casi los mismos que hemos visto:

```
# cd ~/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/
# virtualenv -p python3 venv-desa
# . venv-desa/bin/activate
# pip install -r desa-requirements.txt
```

o bien

```
# cd ~/Proyectos/Mi-proyecto/
# virtualenv -p python3 venv-test
# . venv-test/bin/activate
# pip install -r test-requirements.txt
```

Como te decía esta es una alternativa bien sencilla y sobre todo clara de entender, seguramente hay herramientas y procedimientos mejores y más automatizados, pero este esquema, al menos a mí me ha sido muy práctico.

Comment: Encontré una solución, que podría ser una alternativa. Aunque no es tan simple de gestionar. En un rato mas la publico. Tremendo aporte, muchas gracias Patricio.